# Uniform convergence of $1/g_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(g_n)_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly to $g$ on a compact set $K$. If $g(x)\neq 0$ on $K$, show $(1/g_n)_n$ converges uniformly on $K$ to $1/g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $g$ is also continuous, and hence uniformly continuous on $K$, so set $\min_{x\in K}|g(x)|=m>0$, then find some $N$ such that $|g_{n}(x)-g(x)|<m/2$ for all $x\in K$ and $n\geq N$, then $\inf_{x\in K}|g_{n}(x)|\geq m/2$ for all $n\geq N$. Given $\epsilon>0$, find $N'>N$ such that $|g_{n}(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in K$ and $n\geq N'$. Then $\left|\dfrac{1}{g_{n}(x)}-\dfrac{1}{g(x)}\right|=\dfrac{\left|g_{n}(x)-g(x)\right|}{|g_{n}(x)||g(x)|}\leq\dfrac{2}{m^{2}}\epsilon$ for all $x\in K$ and $n\geq N'$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note $\min_{x\in K} |g(x)|=m>0$ and
$$\left|\min_{x\in K} |g_n(x)|-m\right|\leq \max_{x\in K}||g_n(x)|-|g(x)||.$$
Moreover, for $x\in K$,
$$\left|\frac{1}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{g_n(x)}\right|\leq \frac{\max_{x\in K}|g_n(x)-g(x)|}{\min_{x\in K} |g(x)|\min_{x\in K} |g_n(x)|}.$$